# How to display encrypted image in browser without decrypting it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

```
  public static class ImageEncryption
    {
        static string FILENAME = @"D:\Documents\Watermark\EBCDocument\EBC021700725665\test.pdf\Page1.jpg";
        static string ENCFILENAME =  @"D:\Documents\Watermark\EBCDocument\EBC021700725665\test.pdf\Page1.jpg";
       public static void ImageTripleDESCrypto()
        {
            //Create instance of DES
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            //Generate IV and Key
            des.GenerateIV();
            des.GenerateKey();
            //Set Encryption mode
            des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            //Read
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
            //Store header in byte array (we will used this after encryption)
            var header = ms.ToArray().Take(54).ToArray();
            //Take rest from stream
            var imageArray = ms.ToArray().Skip(54).ToArray();
            //Create encryptor
            var enc = des.CreateEncryptor();
            //Encrypt image
            var encimg = enc.TransformFinalBlock(imageArray, 0, imageArray.Length);
            //Combine header and encrypted image
            var image = Combine(header, encimg);
            //Write encrypted image to disk
            fileStream.Close();
            File.WriteAllBytes(ENCFILENAME, image);


        }
    public static byte[] Combine(byte[] first, byte[] second)
    {
        byte[] ret = new byte[first.Length + second.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, ret, 0, first.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, ret, first.Length, second.Length);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting it in a folder and using the url to display. If it is an image, it will be shown, even if encrypted..

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve?What is the use of encryption if you need it to be displayed ?

Comment: I am trying to render my encrypted image to browser at the same time i want if any body download that image it should downloaded as encrypted image.

Comment: What if the user chose to take screen shot and crop the browser rendered image?

Comment: One of the reliable ways to prevent reusing the image is to use watermarks and random places for different images.

Comment: About the only way to do this is to write a browser plugin - Java app, maybe Flash would do it, neither of which work on all browsers these days.  Even then it won't get around screen captures, etc.

Comment: @Amit I try to Pull it from folder but image is not displaying in browser

Comment: @KumarShubham Are you using absolute path or relative path?

Comment: @Amit    I am using Absolute path

Comment: Use relative path in the browser for the directory where image is stored.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could image is if the client and server had prearranged unique keys so that I would be the client that decrypts it. Otherwise there would be no point in encrypting it because it would be public to anyone who had access to the page. This is just opinion though.

Comment: Point is any body see the image from web page but when download that image it should download as encrypted image

Comment: Ok I think I get what you are saying, you want to be able to show the image, but if someone is trying to download it they only get an unusable encrypted version. In that case I'm not sure if it is possible, due to the fact that in order for the browser to show the image it has to be an image and not encrypted. This isn't my expertise so take what I say with a grain of salt. Perhaps check copy safe web, that looks promising. Sorry I couldn't be more help